# The array dont save my numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn C# and doing some questions i googeld. This is the task to do:

*"Beginner level:
The task is to make
a dice game where the user throws 3
Each 12-sided dice (numbers
shall be randomly selected and stored in an array / field or list).
Add up the total of the dice and show on the screen.
Create a function / method that accepts a figure
(the total sum of the dice). Function / method
should return the text "Good throw" if the figure
is higher or equal to 20.
In all other cases, the text
"Sorry" is returned.
Call the function / method in the main method
and prints the total and the text.

Advanced level:
This is an extension of the task where you must use a class to simulate a dice. The user shall have the option of writing a x y-sided dice himself.
If the total sum of a roll of the dice generates a score that is> 50% of the maximum score, the words "good throw" is displayed.
This logic can be in your main method.
Create the class described in the class diagram and use appropriate
way in your code."*

The thing is that i cant get it to work, the array in my class do not save my numbers im typing in... I only get the reslut 0. I think i have just done some big misstake i cant see...

This is the Main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Dice> _Dice = new List<Dice>();
    int a = 0;
    int times = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Write how many times you want to repeat the game:"));

    while (a != times)
    {
        int antThrow = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Write how many times you want each dice to get thrown:"));
        int xChoice = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Write how many dice you want to throw:"));
        int yChoice = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Write how many sides you want each dice should have:"));

        _Dice.Add(new Dice(xChoice,yChoice, antThrow));
        a++;
    }

    int e = 1;
    foreach (var item in _Dice)
    {
        Interaction.MsgBox(string.Format("Result of game {0}: {1}", e++, item.Tostring()));
    }
}
```

This is the Dice class:

```
class Dice
{
    static int _xChoice, _yChoice, _throw;
    static List<int> sum = new List<int>();
    static int w = 0;
    static int _sum;
    static int[,] dice = new int[_xChoice, _yChoice];

    public string Tostring()
    {
        int half = _sum / 2;

        if (half <= _sum/2)
        {
            return "Good throw!" + _sum;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Bad throw!";
        }
    }

    void random()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (w != _throw)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dice.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dice.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    dice[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, _yChoice);
                    _sum += dice[j, i];
                    sum.Add(_sum);
                }
            }

            w++;
        }
    }

    public Tarning(int Xchoice, int Ychoice, int throw)
    {
        _throw = thorw;
        _xChoice = Xchoice;
        _yChoice = Ychoice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe a problem with less amount of code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: The issue is `static`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dice = new List<DiceLogic>();
        int a = 0;
        int times = GetTimes();
        while (a != times)
        {
            int antThrow = GetAntThrow();
            int xChoice = GetXChoice();
            int yChoice = GetYChoice();

            dice.Add(new DiceLogic(xChoice, yChoice, antThrow));
            a++;
        }
        int e = 1;
        foreach (var item in dice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result of game {0}: {1}", e++, item.Tostring());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int GetTimes()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write how many times you want to repeat the game:");
            int times;
            var result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out times);
            if (result) return times;
            Console.WriteLine("Value must be a number.");
        }
    }

    private static int GetAntThrow()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write how many times you want each dice to get thrown:");
            int antThrow;
            var result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out antThrow);
            if (result) return antThrow;
            Console.WriteLine("Value must be a number.");
        }
    }

    private static int GetXChoice()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write how many dice you want to throw:");
            int getXChoice;
            var result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out getXChoice);
            if (result) return getXChoice;
            Console.WriteLine("Value must be a number.");
        }
    }
    private static int GetYChoice()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write how many sides you want each dice should have:");
            int getXChoice;
            var result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out getXChoice);
            if (result) return getXChoice;
            Console.WriteLine("Value must be a number.");
        }
    }
}


public class DiceLogic
{
    public string Tostring()
    {
        int maxScore = _diceSides*_dices;

        if (_result >= maxScore / 2)
        {
            return "Good throw! " + _result;
        }
        return "Bad throw! " + _result;
    }

    private readonly int _dices;
    private readonly int _diceSides;
    private readonly int _throwDice;
    private int _result;

    private void CalculateResult()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < _dices; i++)
        {
            int currentResult = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < _throwDice; j++)
            {
                currentResult = rnd.Next(0, _diceSides);
            }
            _result += currentResult;
        }
    }

    public DiceLogic(int dices, int diceSides, int throwEachDice)
    {
        _dices = dices;
        _diceSides = diceSides;
        _throwDice = throwEachDice;
        CalculateResult();
    }
}
```

This is an example of how you could implement what they are asking, go through te code line by line with the debugger so you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is in the **static** keyword. *Static field* means that there's only
*one field* for all the instances, which is not your case: you need each instance of `Dice` has its own fields' values.

```
class Dice {
  // no static here 
  private int _xChoice, _yChoice, _throw;
  // no static here 
  private List<int> sum = new List<int>();
  // no static here 
  private int w = 0;
  // no static here 
  private int _sum;
  // no static here 
  private int[,] dice = new int[_xChoice, _yChoice];
  // BUT, you want a random generator for all the instances, that's why "static"
  private static Random rnd = new Random();

  // When overriding method mark it with "override"
  // And Be Careful with CAPitalization: 
  // the method's name "ToString" not Tostring
  public override string ToString() {
    ...
  }

  void random() {
    // Do not create Random generator each time you call it:
    // It makes the random sequences skewed badly!
    // Istead use one generator for all the calls, see the code above
    // private static Random rnd = new Random();
    // Random rnd = new Random();
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You never call the method `random()`. Therefore, the value of your member variable `_sum` is never changed and remains `0`. You need to call the method `random()` somewhere. You should probably make it `public` and call it from your main method after you have set up all your dice.
2. Furthermore, your member variables in the `Dice` class are all `static`! That means that the different `Dice` instances will all share the same values. I think this is not intended. You should make the variables instance variables by removing the `static` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your method Tarning is not called and it takes a reserved word “**throw**” [I believe it was supposed to be thorw]. The method is not void so it must return a type.

Random() is not invoked and does display anything.

Dice has not constructor that has 3 arguments within its braces but it’s declared as **_Dice.Add(new Dice(xChoice,yChoice, antThrow));**